# InnerHtml drives me crazy

Tags: javascript, html

To insert HTML code using javascript dynamically, we use innerHTML after a tag is selected. Simple, but for me is not working. I've seen some links on SO and internet to do that.

My code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Javascript experiments</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/app_item.css"/>
  <!--script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="assets/inserting_items.js"></script-->
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      function insert_items(how_much){
        for(var i=0; i < how_much; i++){
            var div_cont = document.getElementById("my_container");
            console.log(div_cont);
            div_cont.innerHtml = "<div class='desc_container'><span class='desc'>Some text</span></div>";
        }
     }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
      <h3>Inserting code dynamically in webpage.</h3> 
  </header>
  <p>By pressing the button, it will insert items in webpage</p>
  <label>How much:</label>
  <input type="text" id="how_much"/>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="insert_items(document.getElementById('how_much').value)"/>
  <div id="my_container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I press the button, nothing occurs. Dynamic content isn't added on the page. I tested on Firefox and Chrome. Even the simplest `div_cont.innerHtml = 'asdasd'` won't work.
This code is so simple but isn't working. Is there a specific reason for this behavior?

Comment: `.innerHTML` - casing is important

Comment: What a shame. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to your capitalization of `.innerHTML`:

```
div_cont.innerHTML = "<div class='desc_container'><span class='desc'>Some text</span></div>";
```

Comment: Sorry for this shameful mistake. This little detail caused some destruction.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `div_cont.innerHTML = 'asdasd'`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Javascript experiments</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/app_item.css" />
  <!--script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" href="assets/inserting_items.js"></script-->
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function insert_items(how_much) {
      for (var i = 0; i < how_much; i++) {
        var div_cont = document.getElementById("my_container");
        console.log(div_cont);
        div_cont.innerHTML = "<div class='desc_container'><span class='desc'>Some text</span></div>";
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h3>Inserting code dynamically in webpage.</h3> 
  </header>
  <p>By pressing the button, it will insert items in webpage</p>
  <label>How much:</label>
  <input type="text" id="how_much" />
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="insert_items(document.getElementById('how_much').value)" />
  <div id="my_container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The console doesn't throw errors when you assign values to undefined object members.